# Create archive to publish in AppStore

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I have a **detach** app because I needed to install firebase.
I've never created an application for Iphone before

I read:
https://docs.expo.io/versions/v28.0.0/guides/offline-support.html
https://docs.expo.io/versions/v28.0.0/distribution/building-standalone-apps
https://docs.expo.io/versions/v19.0.0/workflow/advanced-expokit-topics#configuring-the-js-url

Unfortunately, when building an application, it still creates it in development mode. (I still need a local server)
1. How to do standalone in production mode?
2. How to attach a bundle so that the application works offline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. How to do standalone in production mode?

Expo detach your project build configuration to decide local or production mode. So in your case:

Go to your `Target` -> `Edit Scheme` -> `Run`-> Select `Release` mode

For `Archive`, it is pre-selected `Release` so it is production mode when you archive the project and submit to Apple.

> 2. How to attach a bundle so that the application works offline?

You have to control the values of `updates` for the `app.json`.
https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/configuration.html#updates